# how to get each id of each selected in M2M djnago

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

i want to get the ID of selected imeis

```
class Mobile(models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    imei = models.ManyToMany(Imei,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Imei(models.Model):
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=13,unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

if i selected 10 imei's i want to get 10 ID's of selected imeis!?
i tried this ways but no one worked !

```
instance.imei__id 
instance.imei.id
instance.imei_id
```

i appreciate your helps

Comment: What do you mean with "selected items"? Whee do you select these?

Comment: sorry i mean selected imeis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instance.imei` is a *manager*. You can access the `Imei` objects with:

```
instance.imei.all()  # QuerySet of Imei objects
```

Or if you are only interested in the primary keys (`pk`s) of the `Imei` objects:

```
instance.imei.values_list('pk', flat=True)  # QuerySet of Imei primary keys
```

**EDIT**: You can update all values with:

```
instance.imei.all().update(active=False)
```

You can for example run it in a `CreateView` with:

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Mobile
    # …

    def form_valid(self, form):
        result = super().form_valid(form)
        self.object.imei.all().update(active=False)
        return result
```

or for a "nested" `ManyToManyField`:

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Mobile
    # …

    def form_valid(self, form):
        result = super().form_valid(form)
        Imei.objects.filter(selectmobile__item=self.object).update(active=False)
        return result
```

Comment: thanks , i have a boolean field in Imei i want to update it using signals whenever an imei selected i update **Imei**  Imei.objects.filter(pk=instance.imei.values_list('pk',flat=True)).update(
            active=False
        )  . this raised this error (The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.)

Comment: @art_cs: in that case, you don't need to first fetch the ids, you can just update these, like in any manager, see edit.

Comment: Imei.objects.filter(instance.imei.all).update(active=False) it raise this error (cannot unpack non-iterable method object
)

Comment: @art_cs: but you don't need that, see edit, you can simply access the values with `instance.imei.all()`, so you can update these with `instance.imei.all().update(active=False)` to update all related `Imei`s with `active=False`.

Comment: but doesnt update Imei , still remain active=True in Imei model

Comment: @art_cs: it will only update the ones that are related. Note that a signal on `Mobile` will *not* fire when the items are added, since that is not a save of the object itself, you need a `m2m_changed` for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#m2m-changed It does not run a `save()` on the `Mobile` model at all to update the m2m models. So when you create an object, the m2m is *empty*. It is only later that the form will add the objects to the m2m.

Comment: @art_cs: furthermore signals are a bit of an antipattern: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/ it is probably both simpler and more reliable to call a function in a view where you update the m2m of the `Mobile` object.

Comment: sorry still i cant update Imei > active field whenever i create Mobile object . the sender=Mobile

Comment: @art_cs: but the signal should not register on that, since as said, if you *create* an object, then that object has *no* m2m objects. Since it *first* needs to create an object, to retrieve a primary key, and *then* it can use that primary key to add m2m relation objects.

Comment: where should i put instance.imei.all().update(active=False) ? in Mobile CreateView ? but didnt work !

Comment: now i add another model and used through to Mobile model something like this (class CustomerModel(models.Model): name=CharField() mobile = ManyToManyField(SomeModel,through='Mobile') ) how to access imei , i tried self.object.mobile_set. not worked

Comment: @art:cs: then it is `self.object.mobile.all().update(...)`. Since that is the name of the relation.

Comment: @art_cs: if however `Mobile` is a "through" model, you need to add (at least) two `ForeignKey`s that refer to the origin and target models of the m2m.

Comment: self.object.mobile.all().update(...) and it doesnt work

Comment: SelectMobileCustomer is SelectMobile

Comment: @art_cs: what is the type of `self.object`? Exactly what model does the view wraps?

Comment: MobileCustomer , i used inlineformset with CreateView SelectMobile is the formset

Comment: @art_cs: what about `self.object.selectmobile_set.all().update(..)`?

Comment: doesnt work i should access to imei's i did it also

Comment: @art_cs: you did not specify a `related_name` in the `ForeignKey`?

Comment: @art_cs: eactly what do you mean with "it only work for selectmobile's field"?

Comment: if i want to update a field inside SelectMobile this works (self.object.selectmobile_set.all().update(..))

Comment: @art_cs: and what do you want to do instead?

Comment: update Imei field (active=False) whenever i selected an imei

Comment: imei in SelectMobile is an M2M field

Comment: didnt work yet , this is my entire relation models http://dpaste.com/15YQVF5

Comment: i much appreciate your helps

Comment: i make a new question with all models class can you help me please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62466783/update-method-in-createview-django-for-manytomany-field